# Get the hours and minutes until 10am the next day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails, how can I calculate the time until 10am the next day, and report it in hours and minutes?

For example, if it was 11:30pm, I would get "10 hours 30 minutes"?

Things I'm trying:

```
// Get the right day 

if (**before 10am**)
  days = Time.now
else
  days = Time.now + 1.days

//
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the precise format you want using just Rails (ActiveSupport + ActiveView that is) but you can get close:

```
time_now = Time.zone.now
time_tomorrow_at_10 = Time.zone.tomorrow.at_beginning_of_day.advance(hours: 10)

distance_of_time_in_words(time_now, time_tomorrow_at_10) # => about 24 hours
```

Note that the usage of `Time.now` is almost always incorrect as it doesn't take your app's configured time zone into account.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a time variable. The following is not neat but is workable.

```
tomorrow_10_am = Time.new((Date.today + 1).year,
                          (Date.today + 1).month,
                          (Date.today + 1).day,
                          10
                          )
time_calculation = ((tomorrow_10_am - Time.now)/1.minute).round
result = (time_calculation / 60).to_s + " hours " + (time_calculation % 60).to_s + " minutes"

# the result is the time difference in hours and minutes format
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't have precise helper for that. If you use `distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, to_time)`, it will return rough estimation:

```
distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, Date.tomorrow + 10.hours)
#=> "1 day"
```

So you can use [this gem](https://github.com/radar/dotiw) to get really precise time.

```
time_ago_in_words(Date.tomorrow + 10.hours)
#=> "22 hours, and 30 minutes"
```